# Working with unicode encoded Strings from Active Directory via python-ldap

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, active-directory

I already came up with this problem, but after some testing I decided to create a new question with some more specific Infos:

I am reading user accounts with python-ldap (and Python 2.7) from our Active Directory. This does work well, but I have problems with special chars. They do look like UTF-8 encoded strings when printed on the console. The goal is to write them into a MySQL DB, but I don't get those strings into proper UTF-8 from the beginning.

Example (fullentries is my array with all the AD entries):

```
fullentries[23][1].decode('utf-8', 'ignore')    
print fullentries[23][1].encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print fullentries[23][1].encode('latin1', 'ignore')
print repr(fullentries[23][1])
```

A second test with a string inserted by hand as follows:

```
testentry = "M\xc3\xbcller"
testentry.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print testentry.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
print testentry.encode('latin1', 'ignore')
print repr(testentry)
```

The output of the first example ist:

```
M\xc3\xbcller
M\xc3\xbcller
u'M\\xc3\\xbcller'
```

Edit: If I try to replace the double backslashes with .replace('\\\\','\\) the output remains the same.

The output of the second example:

```
Müller
M�ller
'M\xc3\xbcller'
```

Is there any way to get the AD output properly encoded? I already read a lot of documentation, but it all states that LDAPv3 gives you strictly UTF-8 encoded strings. Active Directory uses LDAPv3.

My older question this topic is here: [Writing UTF-8 String to MySQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python)

Edit: Added repr(s) infos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, know that `print`ing to a Windows console is often the step that garbles data, so for your tests, you should `print repr(s)` to see the precise bytes you have in your string.

You need to find out how the data from AD is encoded.  Again, `print repr(s)` will let you see the content of the data.

UPDATED:

OK, it looks like you're getting strange strings somehow.  There might be a way to get them better, but you can adapt in any case, though it isn't pretty:

```
u.decode('unicode_escape').encode('iso8859-1').decode('utf8')
```

You might want to look into whether you can get the data in a more natural format.

Comment: I am testing on an Ubuntu machine, just for the record. The output for print repr(fullentries[23][1]) is u'M\\xc3\\xbcller', for print repr(testentry) it prints 'M\xc3\xbcller' Edit: Added the info above

Comment: Thank you! Your update does indeed work, you rescued my weekend ;). This does not work with the thumbnailPhoto attribute I get out of the AD, but I think we can find a workaround for that. All pure text strings now look perfect. :)