# Why do I get latin-1 codec error with a Utf8 script, unicode data, and utf8 database?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem with my python 2.7 script. Script is declared in UTF8, the Data I get from Google Search Console API are in Unicode, and the Database where I want to store them is in UTF8 too (UTF-8 Unicode utf8mb4, utf8mb4_general_ci).

If I launch the script on my mac (and store the data on my physical ubuntu server, no problem at all.
If I launch the same script, directly from the server or on my mac through SSH, I get a latin-1 codec error.

I triple checked locale variable on both server and my mac, I get exactly the same values which are :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Encoding of the Ubuntu terminal is in UTF8 two ..

I don't have any idea why my script want to store the data in latin-1 because it is unicode and the base is in utf8. Also, if I specify `data.encode('utf-8')`, the script works but data are not correctly encoded..

Any idea ?

For information, I use the library "Dataset" to make MYSQL requests, so I can't specify any charset anywhere I think.

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQLdb** probably doesn't know that it is supposed to encode to utf8. Therefore, it falls back to its default latin1 charset. Pass `charset='utf8'` as a parameter when you do your request.

```
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(user = 'username', db = 'database', charset = 'utf8')
```

**Update:**

Another option is to use a database query.

```
db.query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;")
```

Hope this helps you out.

[Writing UTF-8 String to MySQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python)

http://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Thx a lot, with "Dataset" library I don't found how to put the equivalent to `charset = 'utf8'`  yet because the `dataset.connect('MY_URL', engine_kwargs={'encoding':'utf8'})` doesn't work. But at least your comment makes me understand where the problem is.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I just assumed that you were using MySQLdb. I dug a bit deeper for you. Hope the update will help you.

Comment: Thanks again for your time Philipp, I tried what the doc says but it doesn't work. 
I chose Dataset because it simplifies a lot usage of Mysql database with python and I would like to avoid learning all the borring and complicated Mysql syntax, but obviously my linux server will not let me go this way :)

Comment: Finally I found a way to make it work with dataset lib !

`dataset.connect('mysql://username:password@server/database?charset=utf8mb4)`, for those who are interested in :)