# Error encoding Python

Tags: python

i'm having some issues with python encode and cant find any help in the web!

In the first, i begin developer in python a 3 months ago, so i'm a beginer!

I'm doing some scraper and i having a issue with a encode, the error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/thiago/crawler/src/link_produto.py", line 145, in <module>
 crawler(link)
File "/home/thiago/crawler/src/link_produto.py", line 125, in crawler
 cursor.execute(sql)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line       181, in execute
query = query.encode(db.unicode_literal.charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in    position 5013: ordinal not in range(256)
[Finished in 1.633s]
```

My Code here:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import MySQLdb
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import json

def crawler(link_cat):
html = requests.get(link_cat)
soup = bs(html.content, "lxml")

for div in soup.find_all('a', {"class" : "last-page"}):
    lp = div['href']
regex = r"^.*\/([0-9]+)\/$"

strlp = lp


matches = re.search(regex, strlp)

if matches:
    for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
           groupNum = groupNum + 1
           valor_final = matches.group(groupNum)
           valor_final = int(matches.group(groupNum))

print('1º STEP: A Qtd de páginas da categoria é', valor_final)





vetor = []
for i in range(0, valor_final):

   vetor.insert (i,'%s%d' %(link_cat, i+1) + '/')
   print(i)
   vetor[0] = link_cat



for i in vetor:
    html = requests.get(i)
    soup = bs(html.content, "lxml")
    for a in soup.find_all('a', {"class" : "product-li"}):
        last_update = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
        rank_cat = str(i)
        rank_pagina_cat = 2
        rank_site = 300


        url = requests.get(a['href'])
        html_sku = url.content


        soup_sku = bs(html_sku, 'html.parser')

        title = soup_sku.title.string

        SKU = soup_sku.find(string=re.compile("digo.*"))

        rows = soup_sku.find_all('tr')
        specList = []


        for row in rows:
            data = row.find_all('td')
            spec = {data[0].get_text() : data[1].get_text()}
            specList.append(spec)



        product = {'title': title, 'sku' : SKU[+7:], 'spec' : specList}
        productJSON = json.dumps(product)

        productJSON = productJSON.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')

        print(a['href'], last_update, rank_cat, rank_pagina_cat, rank_site, SKU[+7:], str(productJSON), 'title')



        db = MySQLdb.connect("ipbd","user","pass","bd" )
        cursor = db.cursor()

        sql = "INSERT INTO link_produto(desc_link, \
               last_update, rank_cat, rank_pagina_cat, rank_site, sku, json_encode, titulo) \
               VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s' )" % \
               (a['href'], last_update, rank_cat, rank_pagina_cat, rank_site, SKU[+7:], productJSON, title)

        #try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Commit your changes in the database
        db.commit()
        #except:
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        db.rollback()

        # disconnect from server
        db.close()

        print ("3ºSTEP:", a['href'])
link = 'https://www.linktodoscrapper.com'
crawler(link)
```

`

I understand that I am not using the best practices of code organization, so if you want to give an opinion on how I should structure this code, I thank you

Comment: Try to add `charset="utf8"` in `MySQLdb.connect()`. Related: [Writing UTF-8 String to MySQL with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python)

Comment: First, before we even get to this problem: do not use `%` to build SQL strings with your values in them; use parameter placeholders in your SQL and pass your values as arguments to `execute`. If you don't understand why, [here's the obligatory xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: And I suspect the problem you're asking about may ultimately be caused by the same line. If any of those strings you're trying to format into the SQL string are `unicode` rather than `str`, they're going to be automatically encoded with your default encoding, which is probably not UTF-8, because that's what `%s` means. But database connectors are smarter than `%`, and will make sure to encode any `unicode` arguments into the encoding you specified for the database. Although you do have to specify the encoding, as Delgan points out, before that can work.

Comment: I found no less than four StackOverflow questions immediately on googling `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character`. Perhaps you should start by reading through some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942888/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character).

Comment: Yes you are right, i do it and works, `charset="utf8" in MySQLdb.connect()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to add `charset='utf8'` to your connection string.

See the answers in the similar question:
[Python & MySql: Unicode and Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365660/python-mysql-unicode-and-encoding)